# Mockito Coverage help (intern)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, jdbctemplate

New to this, only my second day, but I'm having a hard time getting complete coverage for this method.... I think I just don't under stand lambdas correctly? or maybe I just dont understand all of Mockito yet? maybe both...

below is source code under unit test:

```
 List<String> domains = jdbcTemplate.query(
                query,
                (rs, rownum) -> rs.getString(1)
        );
```

This is what I have currently that compiles for some coverage:

```
@Test
    public void test_Repository_getAIPDomains() throws DataAccessException {
        when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(testStringList);
        List<String> testList = Repository.getAIPDomains();
        Assertions.assertEquals("junit", testList.get(0));
    }
```

this doesn't provide coverage for:

```
 (rs, rownum) -> rs.getString(1)
```

I've tried a lot of different things to attempt coverage, but it gets a little messy with resultSetExtractor and other rollbackcallhandler. Any help is greatly appreciated, or even some links to some resources.

Answer (score 0):

where you are using testStringList(expected ) ?
Assertions.assertEquals(testStringList, testList.get(0));
you need to set value in your expected list , then comapre/assert

Comment: I have a initialize list method created, as well as setup method called before each test is ran. So the list contains one item and the string value is "junit". I did switch the statement to reflect what you said though, thanks! ```Assertions.assertEquals(testList.get(0),"junit");``` but still doesnt fix the code coverage issue.